# C++ - why does this code compile when there's no obvious constructor match?

Tags: c++, constructor, new-operator, explicit-constructor

Please consider the following code:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  explicit Foo(double) {}
};

Foo * test();
Foo * test() {
  return new Foo(Foo(1.0));   // (1)
}
```

My question concerns line (1). This is very similar to a bug that took me some time to track down. I hadn't noticed that the type had been specified twice due to a copy/paste error. The correct line is obviously:

```
  return new Foo(1.0);
```

Interestingly, this change also seems to compile warning-free:

```
  return new Foo(Foo(Foo(Foo(1.0))));
```

Why do these examples compile without warnings with clang, even with the `-Wall -Weverything` flags? Why does `Foo::Foo(double)` accept an instance of Foo as a valid `double` argument? Is this some idiosyncratic behaviour of operator new?

My original code was in a larger context, and tested with two LLVM-3-based compilers. Both compiled without warnings or errors. With one, the code actually functioned as I expected and in fact I didn't realise there was a bug for some time. With the other, the instance of Foo behaved very strangely - I can't really describe it properly - it was as if a later copy of the returned pointer "magically" became a different value from the original, resulting in mismatched state between two cooperating objects that were supposed to hold equivalent pointers to the shared Foo, but for some reason held different values after assignment. Until I understand what is going on here, it seems truly bizarre!

Interestingly, the following compiles with both compilers:

```
class Foo { public: explicit Foo(double) {} };
class Bar { public: explicit Bar(double) {} };

Foo * testFoo() { return new Foo(Foo(1.0)); }
Bar * testBar() { return new Bar(Bar(1.0)); }
```

But the following version does not:

```
Foo * testFooBar() { return new Foo(Bar(1.0)); }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The compiler automatically generates a copy constructor `Foo(const Foo&)` and possibly also move constructor depending on exact version/settings `Foo(Foo&&)`. This has nothing to do with operator new, or any pointer magic. Your code simply calls a perfectly normal copy/move constructor defined for you by the compiler. That's all. This behaviour is mandated by Standard. A non-copyable class (at least in the original version of the Standard) is virtually worthless.

If you don't want automatically generated copy constructors, the usual technique is to define them as deleted or private.

Also note that the compiler, in some circumstances, has the right to actually eliminate whole objects from your program, even though normally it should not. If you are doing hijinks with pointer-to-Foo set from in a Foo constructor, you must handle them strictly in all constructors and destructors, meaning having to write your own copy/move constructors, destructors, and assignment operators, else you will come a cropper when the compiler elides an object.

Comment: by "depending on exact version/settings" you mean: depending on what other user-declared constructors/destructors are present

Comment: @mattmcnabb and compiler version! (C++11 for move ctor)

Comment: Whether or not you pass the appropriate -std flag is also important.

Comment: Of course - copy constructor. I had confused myself and thought that the copy ctor wasn't relevant here, but of course it is. Thank you for the explanation.

The actual Foo class contained an instance of another class and passed a pointer to this to subordinate owned objects. Any thoughts as to why this worked OK with one compiler, but not for the other? Lucky coincidence?

Comment: Yes. Some compilers perform copy elision in some circumstances, so it just happened to work if the broken copy ctor was elided.

Answer (score 2):

The constructor you are observing is the copy constructor. Every class has a copy constructor. If you do not declare any copy constructor in your class definition, a copy constructor is *implicitly declared* for you.

The particular signature of the implicitly declared copy constructor depends on your class definition, i.e. on the bases and members — typically is is of the form `X::X(X const &)`, but it may be `X::X(X &)` or `X::X(X volatile &)` if necessary. Exception specifications are as tight as possible. The definition of the implicitly declared copy constructor typically consists of copying bases and members, but it may be defined as deleted under certain circumstances (e.g. if you declare a move constructor).

(In future versions of C++, if you declare a copy or move assignment operator, the implicitly declared copy constructor will be defined as deleted. In of C++11 and C++14 it is defaulted.)

Comment: Right - the copy ctor. I had dismissed that for some reason, but of course now that it's mentioned I realise it's pretty obvious! Thank you for replying.